# Magento2: Unable to save Category from admin

Tags: magento2, category

I am unable to save Category from magento admin.

When i click on save button below error displaying:

> Notice: Undefined index: `category_id` in `vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php` on line 49

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try composer update and see error still persist or not.

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you fix it?

Comment: Unassigned all the products and saved the category, then again assigned the required products to the category. Now working fine

Comment: @Sudheer: Are you able to fix this issue, please let me know, I also facing this issue.

Comment: @PurushotamSharma: yes

Answer (score 8):

Please update your vendor file Storage.php

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php

```
$toSave[] = [
                'url_rewrite_id' => $record->getUrlRewriteId(),
                'category_id' => $metadata['category_id'],
                'product_id' => $record->getEntityId(),
            ];
```

with the below code

```
if(!empty($metadata)){
                $toSave[] = [
                    'url_rewrite_id' => $record->getUrlRewriteId(),
                    'category_id' => $metadata['category_id'],
                    'product_id' => $record->getEntityId(),
                ];
            }
```

Comment: Better override this file instead of directly editing the core file.

Comment: this is not working....

Comment: This is working fine !!!!

Comment: that works thank you. I have magento 2.3.4 if somebody wants to know

Comment: Work for me magento2.3.3

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone comes across this. I encountered the same issue and used the same solution as above but used the override method as editing vendor files is not recommended.

Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Category\Plugin\Storage" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Category\Plugin\Storage" />
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Category\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Product;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\StorageInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;

class Storage extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Category\Plugin\Storage
{
    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    protected $productResource;

    /**
     * Storage constructor.
     * @param UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
     * @param Product $productResource
     */
    public function __construct(UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder, Product $productResource)
    {
        parent::__construct($urlFinder, $this->productResource = $productResource);
    }

    /**
     * @param StorageInterface $object
     * @param array $result
     * @param array $urls
     * @return array|\Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[]
     */
    public function afterReplace(StorageInterface $object, array $result, array $urls)
    {
        $toSave = [];
        foreach ($this->filterUrls($result) as $record) {
            $metadata = $record->getMetadata();
            if (!empty($metadata)) {
                $toSave[] = [
                    'url_rewrite_id' => $record->getUrlRewriteId(),
                    'category_id' => $metadata['category_id'],
                    'product_id' => $record->getEntityId(),
                ];
            }
        }
        if (count($toSave) > 0) {
            $this->productResource->saveMultiple($toSave);

        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem when was trying to save category with a huge amount of products. Try to switch "Store View" to some store (not "All store views") on the top of the category admin page and it should help

Comment: This actually worked. M2 store with many M1 migrated products and occasional weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 2.2.5
I could add the products to the category AFTER i have added the products to the correct website (update attributes => assign to website)